# OnRestoreInstanceState overwriting actions in OnActivityResult

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have a UI flow in which a user drills down into an inner activity, which upon OK sets a text field in the original outer activity.  Under low memory conditions (simulated by the Developer Option "Don't Keep Activities") I get the following sequence of lifecycle methods:

`OuterActivity.onCreate`

`OuterActivity.onRestoreInstanceState`

`OuterActivity.onActivityResult` --> this is where I am calling myEditText.setText()

`OuterActivity.myEditText.onRestoreInstanceState`  --> this is where the old value is getting 'restored'

What is the best practice for handling this problem?

I figure I either need to update the saved instance state of the EditText (how?) or postpone the view update in onActivityResult by posting it to run later (which seems hacky).

Comment: I have dealt with this before.  What I ended up doing in the end was handling this via a Fragment.  The Fragment lifecycle handles this situation much better than the Activity lifecycle.  Fragments have a lifecycle method called onViewStateRestored.  This method is called AFTER the view's state has been restored, so changes are not overwritten by the view's saved state.  I have not been able to find an equivalent Activity lifecycle method, though one may exist.  In the end, I've found working through Fragments rather than Activities tends to offer more control and flexibility.